# aggregate function only returns one value with no function applied

Tags: r, csv, aggregate

I have some data that looks something like this:

```
#   Date    Time    Temp    Intensity   Coupler Attached    Host Connected  Stopped End Of File
1   05/28/15    06:00:00.0  20.329  893.4               
2   05/28/15    07:00:00.0  21.76   5   511.1           
3   05/28/15    08:00:00.0  36.946  79  911.6           
4   05/28/15    09:00:00.0  40.761  60  622.6           
5   05/28/15    10:00:00.0  41.225  24  800.2           
6   05/28/15    11:00:00.0  29.853  14  466.8           
7   05/28/15    12:00:00.0  26.195  5   511.1           
8   05/28/15    13:00:00.0  28.06   9   300.1           
9   05/28/15    14:00:00.0  27.468  6   544.5           
10  05/28/15    15:00:00.0  26.879  4   133.4           
11  05/28/15    16:00:00.0  26  2   238.9           
12  05/28/15    17:00:00.0  25.513  1   173.3           
13  05/28/15    18:00:00.0  24.738  75.3                
14  05/28/15    19:00:00.0  24.062  0               
15  05/28/15    20:00:00.0  23.773  0               
16  05/28/15    21:00:00.0  23.292  0               
17  05/28/15    22:00:00.0  22.812  0               
18  05/28/15    23:00:00.0  22.429  0               
19  05/29/15    00:00:00.0  22.046  0               
20  05/29/15    01:00:00.0  21.76   0               
21  05/29/15    02:00:00.0  21.473  0               
22  05/29/15    03:00:00.0  21.091  0               
23  05/29/15    04:00:00.0  20.901  0               
24  05/29/15    05:00:00.0  20.615  0               
25  05/29/15    06:00:00.0  20.901  1   894.5           
26  05/29/15    07:00:00.0  22.525  8   611.2           
27  05/29/15    08:00:00.0  29.652  42  711.4           
28  05/29/15    09:00:00.0  36.079  22  44.6            
29  05/29/15    10:00:00.0  39.729  77  156.1           
30  05/29/15    11:00:00.0  31.37   19  289         
31  05/29/15    12:00:00.0  32.086  7   233.4
```

I am attempting to use the aggregate function to get average temperatures at each time point. I use this function:

```
aggregate(x=trap7u$Temp,by=list(trap7u$Time),FUN=mean)
```

This gives the following output:

```
Group.1  x
1 06:00:00 NA
```

R does not return any errors, just the above datum. I have attempted casting the columns as different things, as well as attempting to remove any NA's, which returns the same result.

```
str(trap7u)
```

returns:

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1770 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ #               : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Date            : chr  "05/28/15" "05/28/15" "05/28/15" "05/28/15" ...
 $ Time            :Classes 'hms', 'difftime'  atomic [1:1770] 21600 25200 28800 32400 36000 39600 43200 46800 50400 54000 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
 $ Temp            : num  20.3 21.8 36.9 40.8 41.2 ...
 $ Intensity       : num  893 5 79 60 24 ...
 $ Coupler Attached: num  NA 511 912 623 800 ...
 $ Host Connected  : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Stopped         : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ End Of File     : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "problems")=Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ row     : int 1769
  ..$ col     : chr "Coupler Attached"
  ..$ expected: chr "a double"
  ..$ actual  : chr "Logged"
  ..$ file    : chr "'~/Desktop/bioinformatic_work/HOBO_files_complete/hobo_files/2015-AUG-offload/trap7u_10733861_150809.csv'"
 - attr(*, "spec")=List of 2
  ..$ cols   :List of 9
  .. ..$ #               : list()
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_integer" "collector"
  .. ..$ Date            : list()
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
  .. ..$ Time            :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ format: chr ""
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_time" "collector"
  .. ..$ Temp            : list()
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_double" "collector"
  .. ..$ Intensity       : list()
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_double" "collector"
  .. ..$ Coupler Attached: list()
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_double" "collector"
  .. ..$ Host Connected  : list()
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
  .. ..$ Stopped         : list()
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
  .. ..$ End Of File     : list()
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
  ..$ default: list()
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_guess" "collector"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "col_spec"
```

What I am trying to get is the mean Temp values for each time, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Try changing the data type of the column `Temp` to numeric in your data frame before you run the aggregate, i.e., `trap7u$Temp <- as.numeric(trap7u$Temp)`. Then try `aggregate(x=trap7u$Temp,by=list(trap7u$Time),FUN=mean)` again. It worked for me.

Comment: @ikop its still giving me the same single result.

Comment: what data types are the columns in your data frame (`str(trap7u)`)?

Comment: Are you sure there are no `NA`s in `Time?` Have you tried `aggregate(x=trap7u$Temp,by=list(trap7u$Time),FUN=function(x)mean(x,na.rm=T))`?

Comment: I'm still getting the same results, even when I add na.rm=TRUE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143457/discussion-between-ikop-and-erin).

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.